# Can a TV be mounted directly into a heavy wooden entertainment center?

Tags: mounting

My dad has a built in entertainment center that is buit to accommodate an old CRT television.  As such, the entertainment center itself is fairly deep (call it 24" or so), but the cavity for the television itself exposes a 24" high by 27" wide area.  There is, however, a 2" overhang wherein the shelf on which the TV would sit stands proud of the cavity, extending further than the wall.

Looking at new 40" flat screen TVs, I see that the most common width appears to be something on the order of 32", meaning that any 40" TV I get to fill the cubby heightwise would extend beyond the cubby intended, and spill over into the cubby next to it.

Because of the 2" shelf, I see no problem **if and only if** I could somehow mount the TV securely.

Unfortunately, the sentimental value of the entertainment center is such that replacing it or even cutting it is out of the question.

I am considering 2 options:

1. Mount the TV to a stud behind the entertainment center.
2. Mount the TV directly to the wood (and it is real wood) of the entertainment center itself.

I don't like Option #1, because it would involve some really tricky mounting, in a small space, and the bracket would have to extend more than 2 feet to get the TV to stand proud of the cubby's side.

The question is, can one mount the bracket directly to the inside wood?  It is real wood, although its only an inch thick or so.  Is that enough?  Alternatively, if I drilled through that shelf, but backed it into a sistered joint, would that hold?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way:

[Vesa MIS-C mount](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_Display_Mounting_Interface) on the TV?
Presumably the entertainment center shelf is designed to take considerable weight.

You could run a big L bracket down to the floor of the shelf, where you've installed a slot for the bracket to slide into and secure the display.
Since 1" screws are unlikely to hold the full leveraged weight of the display, you could pile 50 or more pounds of weight onto the top of the slot structure. That should eliminate the possibility of your screws yanking out of the cabinet, and also eliminate your having to put screw holes in the, no doubt pretty, front of the cabinet.

Answer (score 4):

I understand not wanting to mess with a piece of family history, but CRTs are not coming back anytime soon and I don't see why you need to preserve the CRT-sized space. I think you should consider tastefully modifying the cabinet (maybe cutting or moving the cubby walls) to accommodate todays flat TVs so that the unit will be useful for another generation or so. Maybe you can enlist your dad to help.

I think having the flat TV hanging off the front of the unit is going to look weird, no matter how you figure out how to mount it. Plus, as you say, you're going to block the side cubbies. It may also make the unit unstable, if the entire weight of the TV is suspended at the front edge.

Answer (score 1):

When our house was built, space above the fireplace was framed out with wood studs as usual, and then the builder added a sheet of plywood (don't remember the exact thickness, but I would hazard a guess of 0.5".)

Our 46" television is mounted directly onto the plywood sheet, and weighs around 46lbs. Have never had a problem with any sort of sagging or weakening of the mount. I've tried pulling on the mount with as much weight as I could muster (I'm guessing around 100+ lbs) and it has stayed solid.

I don't think you'll have a problem mounting your television onto an inch-thick slab of wood.